# Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message ' on Google API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I have copied the code in their documentation on this site: [here](http://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php).

I have changed the JSON on these below. I have generated a fresh files on API on the composer, but I am still having some issues. I'm not sure what have I done wrong. Does this mean their API is way too buggy?

Here is the demo link: [demo](http://ashima.konsum.ph/googleapi2/quick.php)

```
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Ashima');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '/mycredentials.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ .'/mysecret.apps.googleusercontent.com.json');
```

#### Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'file does not exist' in /var/www/mysite/googleapi2/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php:839 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/mysite/googleapi2/quick.php(32): Google_Client->setAuthConfig('/var/www/payrol...') #1 /var/www/mysite/googleapi2/quick.php(80): getClient() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/mysite/googleapi2/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php on line 839

Comment: i got these error too , i am hoping anybody helps you on these

Comment: i'm not sure if you can select the right path on your CLIENt secret path in the wrong way it will bug?

Comment: have you tried this one? https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: thats the latest one thats what i have been using

Comment: wild guess something is wrong with your path it cant find your credentials files.

Comment: i have added here i think this is a good sign? Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid token format' in

Comment: it says here its a bug https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/785 ?

Comment: Have you generated the json token path? there documentation seems terrible

Comment: Based on [google-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), on Did you set the absolute path in 
$client->setAuthConfig('/path/to/client_credentials.json'); ?

Comment: Hi @noogui i just used the  __DIR__ .'/mysecret.apps.googleusercontent.com.json' or is it like this /var/www/site/mysecrep.apps.googleusercontent.com.json ?

Comment: setAuthConfig('/path/to/client_credentials.json') use that as stated [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/988).

Answer (score 2):

The CLIENT_SECRET_PATH is not the CLIENT ID JSON file.

After creating the OAuth 2.0 client IDs for the project from below link you need to create a service account keys, to do this follow those steps:

1. From here https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
2. Click Create Credentials
3. Choose service account keys
4. Select the service account and keep JSON checked.

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm:

1) "CREDENTIALS_PATH" should point to a nonexistent file (in a writable path)

2) "CLIENT_SECRET_PATH" should point to the "ID client OAuth 2.0" credential file, created and downloaded from the Google Console in the Api Credential section.

For a server side php script, like yours, pay attention when creating the "ID client OAuth 2.0" record: on the creation wizard, you should select "other" type of application and not the "web" type.

Regards